# Apache Ignite vs. SQL Server Performance

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database

We are considering using an In-Memory database (such as Apache Ignite) to deal with performance intense BI-like operations. So as a (very primitive) example, I filled Apache Ignite with 250.000 records from a csv-file (14 columns) and did some group-by operations. Previously, I also used the same data to do some performance-tests with MS SQL-Server.

Interestingly and unexpected, MS SQL-Server need about 0.25 seconds to perform this operations, while it takes 1-2 seconds with Apache Ignite.

1, I always was under the impression that Apache Ignite is not only a good option for distributed computing, but also leads to a performance gain compared to a conventional relational database due to its memory oriented architecture. Is that true? Why is it that slow in my example?

2, Did I use Apache Ignite in a wrong way or are there some additional tuning options that I should use?

Here is the source-code I used in my example:

```
  private static Connection conn = null;
  private static Statement stmt = null;
  private static ResultSet rs = null;

  private static void initialize() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException

  {

       // Register JDBC driver.
    Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");

    // Create database tables.
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    // Create table
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE PIVOT_TEST (" +
    " REGION VARCHAR, COUNTRY VARCHAR, ITEM_TYPE VARCHAR, SALES_CHANNEL VARCHAR, ORDER_PRIORITY VARCHAR, ORDER_DATE VARCHAR, ORDER_ID VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "
    + "SHIP_DATE VARCHAR, UNITS_SOLD NUMERIC, UNIT_PRICE NUMERIC, UNIT_COST NUMERIC, TOTAL_REVENUE NUMERIC, TOTAL_COST NUMERIC, TOTAL_PROFIT NUMERIC )");

  }



  private static void fill() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
  {
        // Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");

        // Populate table
        PreparedStatement stmt =
        conn.prepareStatement("COPY FROM 'LINK_TO_CSV_FILE'" +

        "INTO PIVOT_TEST (REGION , COUNTRY , ITEM_TYPE , SALES_CHANNEL , ORDER_PRIORITY , ORDER_DATE , ORDER_ID , SHIP_DATE , UNITS_SOLD , UNIT_PRICE , UNIT_COST , TOTAL_REVENUE , TOTAL_COST , TOTAL_PROFIT ) FORMAT CSV");
        stmt.executeUpdate();

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE INDEX index_name ON PIVOT_TEST(COUNTRY)");
        stmt.executeUpdate();
  }



  private static void getResult() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
  {
        // Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver");

        // Get data
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        rs =
            stmt.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(UNIT_PRICE) AS AVG_UNIT_PRICE, MAX(UNITS_SOLD) AS MAX_UNITS_SOLD, SUM(UNIT_COST) AS SUM_UNIT_COST, AVG(TOTAL_REVENUE) AS AVG_TOTAL_REVENUE , AVG(TOTAL_COST) AS AVG_TOTAL_COST, AVG(TOTAL_PROFIT) as AVG_TOTAL_PROFIT  FROM PIVOT_TEST GROUP BY COUNTRY;");

        retrieveResultSet();      

  }



  private static void retrieveResultSet() throws SQLException
  {
        while (rs.next())
        {
                for(int i=0; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
                {
                    rs.getObject(i+1);
                }
        }
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException

  {

        Ignite ignite = null;

        try

        {

            //--------------------------------CONNECTION-------------------//

            IgniteConfiguration configuration = new IgniteConfiguration();

            ignite = Ignition.start(configuration);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/");

            initialize();

            fill();


            long endPrepTable = System.currentTimeMillis();

            getResult();

            long endGetResult = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Get Result (s)" + " " + (endGetResult - endPrepTable)*1.0/1000);

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
          ignite.close();

          conn.close();

          rs.close();
        }

  }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

There are several things to consider when Ignite is compared to a relational database:

- Ignite SQL engine is optimized for multi-nodes deployments with the RAM as primary storage. Don't try to compare a single-node Ignite cluster to a relational database that was optimized for such configurations. Have a multi-nodes cluster deployed with a whole copy of data in RAM.
- Take into account basic recommendations during data modeling and optimizations like affinity collocation, secondary indexes and others [listed here](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging).
- Plus, keep in mind that relational databases leverage from local caching techniques and depending on the total data size, and a type of a query can complete some queries even faster than Ignite in a multi-node configuration. For instance, I've seen a SQL server completing a query below in 5 ms while Ignite single node cluster in 8 ms and 4-nodes cluster in 20 ms:

  SELECT * FROM Input i JOIN Party pr ON (pr.prt_id) = (i.mbr_id) order by i.input_id offset 0 limit 100

  It was expected because the data set size was around 64GB, and SQL Server could cache a lot in local RAM. Plus, the costs for intra-node communication affected the numbers for 4 nodes cluster in comparison to the single node one.

  To unleash the power of the distributed in-memory computing, preload more data to your cluster or/and force SQL Server to go to disk by checking more complicated queries like the one below:

  SELECT * FROM Input i INNER JOIN Product p ON (i.product_id) = (p.product_id) INNER JOIN Party pr ON (pr.prt_id) = (i.mbr_id) and (pr.session_id=i.session_id) WHERE I.PRODUCT_ID=5 and I.SOURCE_ID=6

  In my case, it took 510 seconds for SQL Server in the same configuration and 64GB of data to finish the query (it had to go to disk). Ignite's 4 nodes cluster finished in 32 seconds and 8-nodes cluster completed in 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the following turning points:

1. Use the collocated flag[1] :

   jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1;collocated=true
2. Introduce a variable for rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount():

   int count = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
   while (rs.next())
   {
      for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
         rs.getObject(i+1);
   }

[1] https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#section-parameters

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#collocate-data-with-data

Comment: The collocated flag helped a little bit. However, I am still much slower than with MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

As with any database, there are many ways to tune and optimise it. And Ignite is designed with different trade-offs than SQL Server -- it's not possible to *guarantee* that it'll be faster in every case.

Having said that, there is some [documentation on improving performance](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/performance-and-debugging#sql-performance-and-usability-considerations).

Things to consider: quarter of a million records isn't that many. Ignite is optimised to work in a cluster where operations can be parallelised. With a single, "hard" query, you might need to increase `queryParallelism` otherwise you're going to be limited to a single thread in each node.

Of course you can also do things like `EXPLAIN PLAN` to make sure it's using the right indexes, etc. As with any optimisation exercise, it's as much an art as a science.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried queryParallelism, but it did not help regarding performance. Is this the right syntax? 

IgniteConfiguration configuration = new IgniteConfiguration();
CacheConfiguration config = new CacheConfiguration("cache_config");
config.setQueryParallelism(number_of_threads);
configuration.setCacheConfiguration(config);        
ignite = Ignition.start(configuration);